# VBA excel, Copy entire row when one column >0 from one spreadsheet to another, automatically and keep info on the first spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet "Capacity" that changes weekly (sometimes daily), I need to copy the entire row when the Value in column K is greater than 0, I need to leave the info in the 1st spreadsheet and if the info changes in the 1st spreadsheet it needs to automatically update in the 2nd spreadsheet. My table starts on row 4 and ends on row 92. Ideally it would run as soon as someone saves the data in the "capacity" spreadsheet. For this I have named the sheet it needs to copy into Sheet 1. I have tried 2 different codes, the first one, will copy it, but I have to run the macros to get it to work, and it puts the new data at the end of the last set of data, I need it to delete the data put in before the changes and only have the new rows. The second one is just not even working for me.

```
Sub Copyto AnotherSheet()

Dim column_k As Long
Dim SrcRow As Long

WithSheets("Capacity")

  column_K=.Cells(.Rows.Count, "K")
  For SrcRow=4To92

      'Cell in column K is>)
     If.Cells(SrcRow, 11).Value>0Then
       .Cells(SrcRow, 11).EntireRow.Copy
       'paste values to first empty row in Sheet1
       Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A"&Sheets("Sheet1").Cells((Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count,"K").End(xlUp).Row+1).PasteSpecialxlValues
End If

Next SrcRow
End Sub
```

Comment: *Spreadsheet* is a word used for the file (workbook). You are talking about worksheets. Are the worksheets in the same workbook as the code? Do you have a column with unique values so we can identify each row more easily? How many columns are there? What should happen if the value in column `K` of worksheet `Capacity` is changed back to 0? Please clarify and add more detail to your post. The screenshots of your data would be most helpful. Also, add some relevant sample data as text that we can copy/paste to test the code.

Comment: 11 columns data starts on row 4 ends on 92. Column K has data that changes. the rows will not change. The only thing that will change on my "capacity" worksheet is the info in column K. The numbers will fluctuate from 0 to 1,000,000. At times the number will go back to 0. Worksheets & code are in the same workbook.  the info in columns a-j will stay constant, k and L will change. 1st column the data starting in B4-Plant 1, C4 - part 1A, D4 - 1.5, E4 - 2.0, F4 -22, G4 - K2000, H4 100%, I4 - 65, J4 - 6%, K4 0 - 1,000,000, L4 - 2000. Column A left out of the table intentionally.

Comment: So you have a fixed range `"A4:L92"`. The unique identifier could be e.g. `B4&"@"&C4` i.e. `Plant 1@part 1A`. You only need to copy values (no formats or formulas). Please confirm. Do columns `K` and `L` contain formulas? In which row does the data start in the destination worksheet `Sheet1`? Should the order in the destination worksheet stay the same as in the source worksheet or should each new row be copied to the bottom?

Comment: I only need to copy values, no formats or formulas. Column L contains a formula, but I only need the value in the column. The data in the destination worksheet starts at B4 just like in the first worksheet. If the info is changed in 1st sheet, I need it to delete the info in destination sheet and only show the rows that have column K >0. So each time a number is changed in K, I need it to delete destination info and pull the new info from sheet 1.

Comment: Does column K contain formulas? If not, does column L recalculate due to the change in K?

Comment: Column K no formulas, column L has a formula that calculates based off of the number put in K and the info in the rest of the specific row. In the destination file, I need it to change based on changes made to column K. If a number greater than 0 is put in K, it will copy the whole row and place it in destination sheet. It will need to delete any info in the destination sheet and only place the rows with numbers greater than 0 from column K. If needed I can place a button at the top to insert the data each time, if I can't figure out how to make it automatically change the info.

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Change: Copy Matching Rows

[image]

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet2(Capacity)`**

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const RANGE_ADDRESS As String = "B4:L92"
    Const CRITERIA_COLUMN As Long = 10
    Const DST_SHEET As String = "Sheet1"
    Const GT_CRITERIA as Double = 0
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Me.Range(RANGE_ADDRESS)
    
    If Not Intersect(srg.Columns(CRITERIA_COLUMN), Target) Is Nothing Then
        
        Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
        Dim scCount As Long: scCount = srg.Columns.Count
        
        Dim Data(): Data = srg.Value
        
        Dim sValue, sr As Long, sc As Long, dr As Long
        
        For sr = 1 To srCount
            sValue = Data(sr, CRITERIA_COLUMN)
            If VarType(sValue) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
                If sValue > GT_CRITERIA Then
                    dr = dr + 1
                    For sc = 1 To scCount
                        Data(dr, sc) = Data(sr, sc)
                    Next sc
                End If
            End If
        Next sr
        
        With Me.Parent.Sheets(DST_SHEET).Range(RANGE_ADDRESS)
            .ClearContents
            If dr > 0 Then
                .Resize(dr).Value = Data
            End If
        End With
        
     End If

End Sub
```

Comment: When I try to run it, like this, it does not pull up a macro to run from

Comment: Don't know what that means. This code runs automatically. You have to copy it to the correct place, to the sheet module of worksheet `Capacity`; not in a standard module (e.g. `Module1`) and not in the `ThisWorkbook` module. In the *Project Explorer*, double-click on the sheet that has `Capacity` in parentheses.